# Why is Lord Alfred Tennyson often written as Alfred Lord Tennyson?

Tags: nouns, names, proper-nouns

Why is *Lord Alfred Tennyson* often written as *Alfred Lord Tennyson*? This occurs with and without a comma after Alfred: *Alfred, Lord Tennyson* and *Alfred Lord Tennyson*. Should *Lord* precede the entire name, and not just the last name?

Comment: Obviously not ... too many people who know what they're doing use *Alfred Lord Tennyson*. The real question is: what are the rules?

Comment: "*This occurs with and without a comma after Alfred*" Yes, that is a mistake.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The simple answer is...

Alfred Tennyson was created a hereditary baron, 1st Baron Tennyson. Barons are known by their title, *Lord Tennyson,* preceded if necessary by their Christian name.

The same applies to current Life Barons, who are not created with hereditary titles. Thus it's *John, Lord Prescott of Kingston-upon-Hull*.

Sons of hereditary peers are given a courtesy title. The sons of barons, that being the lowest order of the peerage, are simply known as *The Honourable*. Alfred's son was The Hon Hallam Tennyson until Alfred died, after which he became Hallam, 2nd Baron Tennyson, or simply Hallam, Lord Tennyson.

The eldest sons of higher ranks of the peerage generally get a courtesy title (the eldest son of a Duke will be granted the use of an Earl's title, and so on). Subsequent sons are known as *Lord,* using the family surname. The second son of one of the Dukes of Devonshire would be [for example] Lord James Cavendish. It's not correct to call that person "Lord Cavendish".

Thus it's possible to distinguish between *Lord James Cavendish* as coming from a higher rank of the peerage than *Alfred Lord Tennyson.*

For a more complicated answer with all the intricacies of the peerage, you will need to consult a reference like *Debrett's*.

Answer (score 0):

Alfred Tennyson should be known as Lord Tennyson, or as the 1st Baron (or lord) Tennyson if one want to make sure that it is him.

If the present 6th (Baron) Lord Tennyson, also was named Alfred, that name would be of no help.

The title (in England the title baron is always substituted by lord) should be used. The use of forename and designation title and then surname is meant for a totally different use.

He is known by this erratic designation because he was a snob, he said no to a baronetcy, but accepted the barony.

Rather vainly he put a "humble" envelope on his lordship, and called himself Alfred, the Lord Tennyson.  A king-like designation, kind of like Alfred, the king of the Tennysons.

The newspapers and press accepted his own way to titulate himself, instead the correct Lord Tebnnuson, without the forename.

He liked to claim that he was humble, a rather ordinary claim by men that are not humble.

Comment: Maybe so, but this doesn't answer the question of why he is known the way he is.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer.

Comment: How does this add to the existing answer?